# Make: Unexpected Behavior with Dependencies and include Statement

Tags: include, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
a.d:
    gcc -m32 -MM -o $@ a.c
    sed 's!a.o!$@ a.o!' --in-place $@

a.o:
    gcc -c -m32 -o $@ a.c

all: a.d a.o

-include a.d
```

The contents of a.d are:

```
a.d a.o: a.c a.h
```

I'm having 2 problems. 1, after running "make all" if I run:

```
touch a.h
make a.d
```

I see this:

```
gcc -m32 -MM -o a.d a.c
sed 's!a.o!a.d a.o!' --in-place a.d
make: 'a.d' is up to date.
```

The a.d rule clearly ran, why do I see "make: 'a.d' is up to date."?

2, after running "make all" when I run this:

```
touch a.h
make a.o
```

I see this:

```
gcc -m32 -MM -o a.d a.c
sed 's!a.o!a.d a.o!' --in-place a.d
gcc -c -m32 -o a.o a.c
```

Why did it also run the a.d rule? There are no dependencies on it.

What I really don't understand is when I replace "-include a.d" with the contents of a.d in the make file, for example:

```
#-include a.d
a.d a.o: a.c a.h
```

I don't see either problem. Shouldn't the include statement make it as if the include file were included directly in the same make file?

This is what my a.h looks like:

```
#define FOO 0
```

And this is a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

void foo(void)
{
    printf("foo %d", FOO);
}
```

I'm using Cygwin 64-bit. Here's my output from make -v:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: FWIW, neither problem occurs when I run this under GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: @Beta I just also tested in 32-bit Ubuntu in a VM and I do still see the problem, GNU Make 3.81. Are you sure that you left the -include ... statement in the make file?

Comment: @Beta I made a typo in one of my edits. I corrected it. You will see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your behaviors are explained by the fact that GNU make tries to rebuild included makefiles; see [How Makefiles are Remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).  So, in your first question the first output is from when make tries to rebuild the `a.d` file and the second output is from after make re-execs itself; it sees that the goal `a.d` is up to date.

In your second question, it runs the `a.d` rule because `a.d` depends on `a.h` and since you include `a.d`, make tries to rebuild it.

For your last question, the reason it doesn't happen if you embed the content directly is that you're not using `include`.

Other interesting things to read are: [Generating Prerequisites Automatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) and [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).  Also maybe [Constructed Include Files](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/) for more background.

Comment: So when an included make file gets modified make restarts the original make file? This isn't really an answer to the 2nd question. I requested that make build a.o, not a.d. Yes a.d depends on a.h, but I requested to rebuild a.o, and a.d is not a dependency of a.o. Plus this problem doesn't occur when I place the contents of the include directly in the file.

Comment: I explained both those things.  Please re-read the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of my answer.  Because `a.d` is included, make will _always_ try to rebuild it even though you explicitly asked for `a.o`.  It doesn't matter what targets you ask to be built, make always tries to rebuild all included files.  Since `a.d` depends on `a.h` and `a.h` is newer and `a.d` is included, make rebuilds `a.d`.  Always.  For the other question, obviously if you don't use the `include` operation there's nothing included, and no include file to rebuild.

Comment: Thank you, this comment is what helped me: "Because a.d is included, make will always try to rebuild it even though you explicitly asked for a.o." Make always checks and possibly updates included targets. Now the behavior is clear. I also got some support from the GNU mailing listing, long story short, it's not a good idea to use dependencies as targets in a make file. The advanced method in the Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation article you provided the link for would be a better way to go. I suppose you are the author of that article? Thanks for helping me.